# Redux-Thunk - how to wait for action creator to finish

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have this action creator:

```
type LoadOpenRequestsResult = ThunkAction<
  Promise<void>,
  IRootState,
  undefined,
  LoadOpenRequestsActions
>;

export const loadOpenRequests: ActionCreator<LoadOpenRequestsResult> = () => {
  [...]
};
```

and I use it like that in my component:

```
public componentDidMount() {
  this.props.loadOpenRequests();
}
```

And I connect my React component using the object version of mapDispatchToProps like this:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loadOpenRequests }
)(MaintenanceOpenListScreen);
```

I’d like to do something when the async action is finished, something like this:

```
public componentDidMount() {
  await this.props.loadOpenRequests();
  doSomethingWhenThisAsyncIsDone();
}
```

but `this.props.loadOpenRequests();` is not a Promise.

Does that mean I cannot use the object version of `mapDispatchToProps`?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/213#issuecomment-428380685

Basically, the answer is yes, you can't use the object version of `mapDispatchToProps`. You have to use the function version like so:

```
public componentDidMount() {
  this.props.loadOpenRequests().then(() => doSomethingWhenThisAsyncIsDone());
}

[...]

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IRootState, undefined, Action>
) => ({
  loadOpenRequests: () => dispatch(loadOpenRequests()),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MaintenanceOpenListScreen);
```